# regarding understanding a code segment on multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am trying to understanding a program, which includes the following code segment

In the code segment, `hypes` is just a parameter setting extracted from a json file.

As shown in the code segment, `background_color = np.array(hypes['data']['background_color'])`, I printed `hypes['data']['background_color']` it out, which is `[0]`
; therefore `background_color` is of shape `(1,)`. I am confused about `gt_bool = (gt_image != background_color)`. How does it work? It seems to me that gt_image should be an array of the image size shape, e.g.,`(640,480)` but `background_color` is of `shape (1,)`, I do not understand how does `gt_image != background_color` work?

```
def _load_gt_file(hypes, data_file=None):
"""Take the data_file and hypes and create a generator. The generator outputs the image and the gt_image."""
    base_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(data_file))
    files = [line.rstrip() for line in open(data_file)]
    for epoche in itertools.count():
        shuffle(files)
        for file in files:
            image_file, gt_image_file = file.split(" ")
            image_file = os.path.join(base_path, image_file)
            gt_image_file = os.path.join(base_path, gt_image_file)

            image = scipy.misc.imread(image_file)
            gt_image = scp.misc.imread(gt_image_file, flatten=True)

      yield image, gt_image


def _make_data_gen(hypes, phase, data_dir):
"""Return a data generator that outputs image samples."""

  background_color = np.array(hypes['data']['background_color'])
  data = _load_gt_file(hypes, data_file)
  for image, gt_image in data:
       gt_bool = (gt_image != background_color)
```

Comment: Probably it is broadcasting, resulting in element-wise `!=` essentially. You can test it out with toy arrays... no?

Answer (score 1):

gt_bool will be a boolean array of the same shape as gt_image, set to True for elements that are equal to background_color and False for elements that are not.